# Firebase-powered app with web service code

Tags: web-services, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-synchronization

I am planning to use Firebase database and want to know how it fits in to the following scenario.

lets say I have a browser app, android app / iOS which uses Web Services to get / insert data, web services talks to the Data Base and returns data to the client.

[image]

This way I have to write code once in my web services and all the clients use that to retrieve and insert data to the database.

If I want to use Firebase, will I be following the same approach of having webservices between the client's and the Firebase DB.

I have done some sample Firebase examples where it it gets data from database directly without web services and in this approach we have to write our logic on each client (Web browser/ android app/ iOs app).

I have looked into this article

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html?showComment=1480073224245#c464815735109872173

The Pattern 2 has the server concept but that does not look appropriate in my scenario.

Can I have my web service and Firebase database and get data Synchronization capabilities.

Correct me if I am wrong and please suggest the approach I need to take.

Thank you for your valuable suggestions in advance.

Thanks & regards,
Rao Burugula

Answer (score 1):

The article you link gives you the most common options for integrating Firebase into your app. Pattern 2 is the easiest way to use the Firebase Database *and* run your own server-side code:

[image: the database sits between the apps and your server]

In this model the Firebase Database sits between the app on the user's device and your back-end code. By using this model, you can still get all the benefits of the realtime synchronization, security rules and scalability, but also have back-end code that runs in a trusted environment.

Of course you can also go for a more traditional three-tier model, where your app server sites between the devices and the database. But in that case the Firebase database won't have direct interaction with your app anymore, so you'll have to take care of the realtime aspects of the synchronization (if you want those) in your own code.

I also recommend reading the [Google Cloud documentation on using the Firebase Database and App Engine's Flexible Environments](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#firebase-appengine-flexible). The architecture described there is the same, but a bit more up-to-date:

[image]